# JDBC Code Won't Create Table

Tags: java, jdbc

Currently trying to insert an object into the Customer table using a test SQL run. However, everything I run the test, the compiler returns the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: error finding Customer
    at edu.depauw.csc480.dao.CustomerDAO.find(CustomerDAO.java:78)
    at edu.depauw.csc480.dao.CustomerDAO.insert(CustomerDAO.java:87)
    at edu.depauw.csc480.dao.DatabaseManager.insertCustomer(DatabaseManager.java:84)
    at edu.depauw.csc480.Test.main(Test.java:18)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'CUSTOMER' does not exist.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
```

I have looked at the code over and over again, however, I can't seem to find an error as it compiles fine, just doesn't run. Below is my create method & find method from my CustomerDAO class.

```
public Customer find(int custID) {
        if (cache.containsKey(custID)) return cache.get(custID);

        try {
            String qry = "select name from CUSTOMER where custID = ?";
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(qry);
            pstmt.setInt(1, custID);
            ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

            String name = rs.getString("name");
            String address = rs.getString("address");
            String email = rs.getString("email");

            rs.close();

            Customer cust = new Customer (this, custID, name, address, email);

            cache.put(custID, cust);
            return cust;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            dbm.cleanup();
            throw new RuntimeException("error finding department", e);
        }
    }

    // Insert new CartItem & returns it if the key does not already exist.

    public Customer insert (int custID, String name, String address, String email) {
        try {
            // make sure that the deptid is currently unused
            if (find(custID) != null)
                return null;

            String cmd = "insert into CUSTOMER(custID, name, address, email) "
                       + "values(?, ?, ?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(cmd);
            pstmt.setInt(1, custID);
            pstmt.setString(2, name);
            pstmt.setString(3, address);
            pstmt.setString(4, email);

            pstmt.executeUpdate();

            Customer cust = new Customer(this, custID, name, address, email);

            cache.put(custID, cust);

            return cust;
        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            dbm.cleanup();
            throw new RuntimeException("error inserting new department", e);
        }
    }
```

Any ideas on what is causing the error?

**EDIT: Here is my CustomerDAO.java class, which handles the creation of the table along with other SQL commands.**

```
public class CustomerDAO {

    private Connection conn;
    private DatabaseManager dbm;
    private Map<Integer, Customer> cache;

    public CustomerDAO (Connection conn, DatabaseManager dbm) {
        this.conn = conn;
        this.dbm = dbm;
        this.cache = new HashMap<Integer, Customer>();
    }

    static void create(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String s = "create table CUSTOMER("
                + "name string, "
                + "custID string, "
                + "address string, "
                + "email string " 
                + "primary key(custID))";
        stmt.executeUpdate(s);
    }

    // Modifies CartItem table and adds foreign key constraints (tables need to already be created)

    //static void addConstraints(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        //Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        //String s = "alter table Customer "
        //      + "foreign key(shoppingCartID) references shoppingCart(shoppingCartID)";
        //stmt.executeUpdate(s);
    //}

    //Finds CartItem object by primary key.

    public Customer find(int custID) {
        if (cache.containsKey(custID)) return cache.get(custID);

        try {
            String qry = "select name from CUSTOMER where custID = ?";
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(qry);
            pstmt.setInt(1, custID);
            ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

            String name = rs.getString("name");
            String address = rs.getString("address");
            String email = rs.getString("email");

            rs.close();

            Customer cust = new Customer (this, custID, name, address, email);

            cache.put(custID, cust);
            return cust;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            dbm.cleanup();
            throw new RuntimeException("error finding department", e);
        }
    }

    // Insert new CartItem & returns it if the key does not already exist.

    public Customer insert (int custID, String name, String address, String email) {
        try {
            // make sure that the deptid is currently unused
            if (find(custID) != null)
                return null;

            String cmd = "insert into CUSTOMER(custID, name, address, email) "
                       + "values(?, ?, ?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(cmd);
            pstmt.setInt(1, custID);
            pstmt.setString(2, name);
            pstmt.setString(3, address);
            pstmt.setString(4, email);

            pstmt.executeUpdate();

            Customer cust = new Customer(this, custID, name, address, email);

            cache.put(custID, cust);

            return cust;
        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            dbm.cleanup();
            throw new RuntimeException("error inserting new department", e);
        }
    }


    //Clears Data from CartItem Table

    void clear() throws SQLException {
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String s = "delete from CUSTOMER";
        stmt.executeUpdate(s);
        cache.clear();
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the JDBC connection URL you're using?  Specifically, what database user are you connecting as and have you verified that the `CUSTOMERS` table is actually owned by/is visible to that user?

Comment: Here is the URL I am using: 

private final String url = "jdbc:derby:shoppingdb";

However, I wasn't sure what to put here. Is there a particular convention? I modeled mine after another piece of code that I found on the net.

Comment: How did the table get created in the database in the first place?  Have you verified the table even exists?

Comment: I wrote the Data Source manually, in a seperate model package (contains three tables). The tables exist, they just don't seem to be creating.

Comment: have you checked that your connection is in the same schema that your `Customer` table is?

Comment: How do I go about doing that?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/584617/1065197

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is Here

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'CUSTOMER' does not exist.
```

the solution ways :

first step, check the connection of create method and query  method are same database or not.

second step, debug your code. Set a breakpoint in the create method, when the method executed
        then  check table 'CUSTOMER' is create or not .

Comment: Yes, I understand that much. However, i'd like to know exactly why that table isn't being created? My create function of my DAO seems sound (copied my CustomerDAO class for reference).

Answer (score 0):

The error says that it can't find the table 'Customer'. Check your dababase if you maybe misspelled the table name. Maybe you have a problem with your connection, try retrieving data from any other table in your database.

Comment: Did you try getting data from any other table in your database?

Comment: Yes, the same exception is thrown (TABLE does not exist). I included my DAO for the Customer table above.

Comment: + "email string, "  you forgot the comma

Comment: Are you sure your table is really created? Go check with a query browser.